# Soft reference LinkedHashMap in Java?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, soft-references

Is there softreference-based LinkedHashMap in Java?  If no, has anyone got a snippet of code that I can probably reuse?  I promise to reference it correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're planning to do this for a memory-sensitive cache, be aware that available memory is a very bad way to regulate anything. In a large-heap environment, you can keep stale objects for a very long time, which slows down overall operation. Time and size-based caches are far better. You may also be interested in this: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj

Answer (score 6):

WeakHashMap doesn't preserve the insertion order. It thus cannot be considered as a direct replacement for LinkedHashMap. Moreover, the map entry is only released when the **key** is no longer reachable. Which may not be what you are looking for.

If what you are looking for is a memory-friendly cache, here is a naive implementation you could use.

```
package be.citobi.oneshot;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class SoftLinkedCache<K, V>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4585400640420886743L;

    private final LinkedHashMap<K, SoftReference<V>> map;

    public SoftLinkedCache(final int cacheSize)
    {
        if (cacheSize < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cache size must be greater than 0");

        map = new LinkedHashMap<K, SoftReference<V>>()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5857390063785416719L;

            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry<K, SoftReference<V>> eldest)
            {
                return size() > cacheSize;
            }
        };
    }

    public synchronized V put(K key, V value)
    {
        SoftReference<V> previousValueReference = map.put(key, new SoftReference<V>(value));
        return previousValueReference != null ? previousValueReference.get() : null;
    }

    public synchronized V get(K key)
    {
        SoftReference<V> valueReference = map.get(key);
        return valueReference != null ? valueReference.get() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best idea I've seen for this is wrapping `LinkedHashMap` so that everything you `put` into it is a [WeakReference](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

UPDATE: Just browsed the source of `WeakHashMap` and the way it handles making everything a `WeakReference` while still playing nice with generics is solid. Here's the core class signature it uses:

```
private static class Entry<K,V> extends WeakReference<Object> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

I suggest browsing [the source](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.java.html) more in depth for other implementation ideas.

UPDATE 2: kdgregory raises a good point in his comment - all my suggestion does is make sure the references in the `Map` won't keep the referent from being garbage-collected. You still need to clean out the dead references manually.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because the references will never disappear, they'll just get cleared. And you'll end up with a map full of dead references. If you look closer at the WeakHashMap code, you'll see that it lazily purges the dead references (I believe using a reference queue).

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [this post](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue098.html). It shows how to implement a SoftHashMap...

Comment: Apache Shiro already has an implementation of this method (with approval) and licensed it under Apache v2. It's packaged with Apache [Shiro][1]. You can find the documentation [here][2] and the source code [here][3]. 


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Shiro
  [2]: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.1.0/apidocs/
  [3]: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.1.0/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/shiro/util/SoftHashMap.html